# Nginx re-write regex pattern gives different result (no match) with regex101.com

Tags: regex, nginx

This page:

https://www.journaldev.com/26864/nginx-rewrite-url-rules

has the below re-write/regex pattern example (*Rewrite static page*):

```
server {
          ...
          ...
          location = /nginx-tutorial 
          { 
            rewrite ^/nginx-tutorial?$ /somePage.html break; 
          }
          ...
          ...
}
```

And the test string:

https://example.com/nginx-tutorial

If I take that pattern and the test string and enter that in https://regex101.com/ I don't get any matches:

https://regex101.com/r/7GHWzI/1

[image]

Are there some additional logic in nginx that matches `/nginx-tutorial` even though the test string starts with: `https://example.com` ?

Or is the convention that the hostname is trimmed out before the re-write regex pattern is applied?

I did not find anything here:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

What am I missing? Any links to documentation that describes this is appreciated.

Comment: `location` and `rewrite` uses a [normalised URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which has been striped of scheme, hostname and query string.

Comment: because the regex starts with: "^" and it means to the first character is the next one, and the URL is with domain, nginx works without domain, try to remove the domain at regex101 and it works: regex: `^\/nginx-tutorial?$` test: `/nginx-tutorial`